# Showing uniform convergence of simple series

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^m+m}$ converges uniformly for $x>1$.

I've tried to use Weierstrass M-test to solve this problem with the series $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m^2}$ but i fail to demand that for all $m>1: |f_m(x)|\le \frac{1}{m^2}$, any other suggestions?

Comment: That series does *not* converge uniformly on $(1,\infty)$. However, it converges uniformly on any interval $[a,\infty)$, if $a>1$.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any idea how can i prove that this function is continuous for not fixed value of x>1 ?

Comment: Take $a\in(1,x)$. Since the convergence is uniform on $(a,\infty)$, $f$ is continuous there. In particular, it is continuous at $x$.

Comment: How can i prove the uniform convergence in the tail (,∞) ? And why it is implicit that f is continuous at x ?

Comment: The uniform convergence on $(a,\infty)$ follows from the Weierstrass $M$-test. And I never wrote that it is implicit that $f$ is continuous at $x$. In fact, I used the same argument as you: if the convergence is uniform in $(a,\infty)$, then, since each function $\frac1{x^m+m}$ is continuous, then $f$ is continuous on $(a,\infty)$.

Comment: @user912299 If $x\geq a$ with a given $a>1$, then $$
\sum\limits_{m = N}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{x^m  + m}}}  \le \sum\limits_{m = N}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{a^m  + m}}}  \le \sum\limits_{m = N}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{a^m }}}  = \frac{1}{{a^N }}\frac{a}{{a - 1}}
$$ implying uniform convergence on $[a,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x > 1} \sum\limits_{m = N}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{x^m  + m}}} & \ge \sum\limits_{m = N}^{2N} {\frac{1}{{\left( {1 + \frac{1}{N}} \right)^m  + m}}}  \ge \sum\limits_{m = N}^{2N} {\frac{1}{{\exp \left( {\frac{m}{N}} \right) + 2N}}} \\ & \ge \sum\limits_{m = N}^{2N} {\frac{1}{{e^2  + 2N}}}  = \frac{{N + 1}}{{e^2  + 2N}}.
\end{align*}
Thus,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to  + \infty } \mathop {\sup }\limits_{x > 1} \sum\limits_{m = N}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{x^m  + m}}}  \ge \frac{1}{2}.
$$
Therefore the convergence cannot be uniform for $x>1$. Can you show the uniform convergence for $x>q$ with a fixed $q>1$?

Comment: First of all thank you so much ! But now i am really confused, my main question was to prove that this function is continuous for every x >1, I thought that if i prove the series is converges uniformly then i could say by some hypothesis which i learned in teachings that the function is continuous since the function sequence is continuous... but now i really have no clue how to solve this :O

Comment: @user912299 This seems to be the case of an XY-problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: Sorry for my bad understanding, is it still possible to ask you to help me out? I don't want to open new post with the main question... even if its in email :o